# MS Dynamics CRM keep a copy of jobs and opportunity after assigning

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

As default in CRM while Assigning Account to another account the entire account with job and opportunities is moved to that and I'm not able to view in my account.

While sharing only the account details is shared no the job and opportunity. My requirement is while assigning I should have a copy of the account.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

So its not entirely clear what you are asking here. So I'm assuming:

- You have a security model where records, e.g. accounts, activities, and opportunities are segregated by owner.
- You want to assign an account with its child activities and opportunities to another owner. Whilst the original owner still maintains access to the account.

Couple of options:

1. Change your security model to remove the segregation entirely.
2. Implemented a security model with a shared team, where users who want to share records assign records to.
3. After assigning the account, share it with the original user. (This could be manual, or automatic with customisations). However extensive user of sharing can cause performance issues you should look into.

Comment: Hey! James thanks for your response, My Current scenario is Say An User 'A' has Account(X) , contacts(X) and opportunities(x) while the User 'A' assigns the Account(X)contacts(X) and opportunities(x) to User 'B' all the accounts(X),contacts(x),opportunities(X) are moved to User'B' but I want the copy of accounts(X),contacts(x),opportunities(X) in the User 'A' also after assigning to User 'B' kindly help me...